# Identify the state of variables in a Java program

Tags: java

This was homework and the task was to state which variables were visible at the points in the code marked `*a*`, ..., `*e*` and what value each one had. Can someone tell me if my solutions were right?

```
public class Zustand {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int DIV = 24;
    int variable;
    int counter = 1;
    {
      // *a*
      variable = counter++;
      int y = 12;
      variable += y;
      counter++;
      // *b*
    }
    final double d;
    {
      counter = 4;
      double a = 10.0;
      {
        d = a + ++counter;
        // c
      }
      counter = 3;
      while (counter > 0) {
        counter--;
        a -= counter;
        // *d*
      }
    }
    variable = variable / DIV;
    // *e*
  }
}
```

First  what variables are there? My answer to this is:

- `final int DIV`
- `int variable`
- `int counter`
- `int y`
- `final double d`
- `double a`

There are 6 variables for each `*a*`, ..., `*e*`. I will assign to the 6-tuple `(DIV, variable, counter, y, d, a)` another 6-tuple  where the component of the tuple is either a number, the character `w`, or the symbol `-`. `-` means it is not visible. If it is a number it means that it is visible and the number is the value which is assigned to the variable. If it is the character `w` it means no value is assigned to the variable but it is visible.

So, this is my solution (is it right?). If something is wrong please give me a hint where my mistake could be.

- `*a*` = (24,w,1,-,-,-)
- `*b*` = (24,14,2,12,-,-)
- `*c*` = (24,14,4,12,15,10.0)
- `*d*` = (24,14,0,12,15,4.0)
- `*e*` = (24,0,0,12,15,4.0)

Comment: Please add in your code System.out.println to show your output

Comment: All the variables declared inside braces `{ }` (a block) will be unavailable when you leave the block. E.g. `y` will not be available at `*e*`

Comment: @JoeTaras I don't know what you mean. System out print is a method what should be the Argument? and where should I put it?

Comment: @Lino is it correct if I say * a * and * b * are Right and  * c * is (24,w,4,-,14,10.0) y is not visible in * c * is that what you meant? I am not sure if variable has an value assigned to it or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use `System.out.println`, it will help you solve it!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int DIV = 24;
    int variable;
    int counter = 1;
    {
      // *a*
      variable = counter++;
      int y = 12;
      variable += y;
      counter++;
      // *b*
      System.out.println("y: " + y);            //  just an example

    }
    final double d;
    {
      counter = 4;
      double a = 10.0;
      {
        d = a + ++counter;
        // c
        System.out.println("d: " + d);             //  just an example

      }
      counter = 3;
      while (counter > 0) {
        counter--;
        a -= counter;
        // *d*
        System.out.println("a: " + a);                   //  just an example
      }
    }
    variable = variable / DIV;
    // *e*

    System.out.println("variable: " + variable);            //  just an example
    System.out.println("DIV: " + DIV);
    System.out.println("d: " + d);
    System.out.println("counter : " + counter);
}
```

In your console, you will see something like this.

> y: 12
>   d: 15.0
>   a: 8.0
>   a: 7.0
>   a: 7.0
>   variable: 0
>   DIV: 24
>   d: 15.0
>   counter : 0

Comment: In * c * does variable has a value?

Comment: One, this was obviously a [homework] exercise in ***reading code***.  The purpose is obviously that he would also be able to ***explain why*** the results are as they are.  How is adding println() helpful with that ?  Two, if he added a println() at point *a* for variable y, he'd get a compile error, no ?

Comment: @RM777  In C ,  I got  d=15.0   , a = 10,  counter =5   they all have these values

Comment: @ErwinSmout - I think this is sound advice - Jin Lee is quite clear that his `System.out.println` statements are only examples, leaving it as a (useful) exercise for the OP to work out exactly what he/she should print. Either way, OP clearly has (almost) understood the code by reading it, and he/she is asking for clarification on how to determine whether that understanding is correct. Printing out the values seems like the perfect way to answer this question on his/her own.

Comment: @JinLee there is also a variable called 'variable' unfortunately I am not able Right now to compile and excecute a Java program. If I would write at the Position * c * . System.out.println("variable: " + variable); would I get an error or a result?

Comment: @RM777  you will get 13.

Comment: @RM777 hey bro. hope I'm not helping you to cheat. lol.  The rest is for you to figure out!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to conflate "scope" and "lifetime" with "visibility".

the `y` and `a` variables are declared inside a { } block, and that means that outside of that block in which they are declared, they ***do not even exist***.  It is wrong, strictly speaking, to say they are not "visible" because being "visible" or not is said of things that ***exist***.  Their scope (existence) is just the block inside which they are declared, and their lifetime "ends when that block is exited".

This must not be taken to mean that the compiler will generate calls for memory allocation upon each entry of the block of code involved, but the language behaves as if the compiler effectively does this.

Furthermore, variables are typically referenceable only after the point where they are declared.  Other languages might be more relaxed in this, and allow, say, the `y` variable to be referenced already at point *a* (I don't know by heart how this is with java specifically and don't have a compiler here right now, but I suspect it will be no - at any rate, referencing before declaring is considered poor practice anyway).

Finally, variables are "visible" throughout their scope and lifetime, except in the case when they are hidden by new declarations.  Some languages allow you to do this :

```
{
 int y = 0;  /* 1st variable */
 {
  long y = 5;  /* 2nd variable, DISTINCT from the first (note the different type), and "hiding" the first */
               /* (so at this point, TWO variables EXIST but only ONE is VISIBLE) */
               /* references to y here will be to the SECOND variable */
 }
}
```

Once again, I don't know by heart how this is with java, but I suspect it might be even disallowed altogether.  Once again, it's relatively poor practice anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to start with: 'what is it that is asked here?'
Because if the question is: which variables were visible at the points in the code?
Then you can't just sum up all the variables you see. But only sum up the variables that are visible at that point in the execution of the 'main' method.

Don't forget to check if variables are already initialized at that point in time.

Don't forget to check the variable type, before writing down, what you think will be the value of a variable.

And look out for shortcuts in code. 
Try to think, if this part of the code wasn't written as short as this, but was written in multiple lines of code, what would the output be? And then see if your first thought is still correct.

that should help you.